Re-position dropdown elements so that they're under a dropdown control
I've got a dropdown control that reads its elements from a table.  The code for such is this:
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label23" runat="server" Text="Escalation Reason"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_Escalation_Reason" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm" Width="250px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
</tr>

When I click on the dropdown, the options pop up above and to the left of the box.  I want them to be directly below the dropdown box, so it looks more like your standard out-of-the-box dropdown.
I took a look at this page, but it only seems to deal with buttons that act as dropdowns, and they all had static list items.  I'm reading mine from a table into a dropdown control, so it's not what I need to do.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/
Can anyone tell me how to get a Bootstrap dropdown to position the selectable list directly below the dropdown control?
EDIT:  The above code produces the following HTML when run:
<tr>
    <td>
        <span id="Label23">Escalation Reason</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="DropDownList_Escalation_Reason" id="DropDownList_Escalation_Reason" class="form-control input-sm" style="width:250px;">
            <option value="0">-----</option>
            <option value="3">Billing needs update to complete client bill</option>
            <option value="9">Client Escalated Request</option>
            <option value="2">Client Facing</option>
            <option value="8">Impact to Client</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>


Can you please show the actual HTML code this produces (instead of server-side code, that no one here has the necessary setup or data for available, to reproduce your result)?

You need to move the DropDownList to next row. Try this -


<tr>
  <td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label23" runat="server" Text="Escalation Reason">
    </asp:Label>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_Escalation_Reason" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm" Width="250px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
  </td>
</tr>



